# How to read files from openshift docker image

Tags: .net, docker, openshift

I have deployed my dotnet project in openshift.currently, it is working fine.i can't access the files from opendhift docker image.actually what i did that i pushed my files to my git repository.then i point my git in openshift for deployment.i have created a new folder in my git, then i build my solution in openshift at the time new docer image is created and app has worked.i can't access the new folders files from openshift.for running my app i have added one environment variable in openshift."DOTNET_STARTUP_PROJECT" :"MYAPP.Csproj".is there any way for reading files from openshift docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get an answer. then I moved to azure Storage.then I am accessing files from azure